# 500 error when trying to post to user's feed at facebbok

Tags: python, django, facebook

We are using the [Authomatic](https://github.com/peterhudec/authomatic) package in order to allow our users to sign in with their social accounts, and also share contents from our site on their social network profiles.

Lately, the Facebook posts started failing with no apparent reason, returning status code 500.

Here is the exception message I am getting from Facebook:

```
{'fp': None, 'status': '', 'startofbody': None, 'startofheaders': None, 'subtype': 'javascript', 'type': 'text/javascript', 'maintype': 'text', 'headers': ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n', 'Cache-Control: no-store\r\n', 'Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8\r\n', 'Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT\r\n', 'Pragma: no-cache\r\n', 'WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "unknown_error" "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."\r\n', 'X-FB-Rev: 1086465\r\n', 'X-FB-Debug: fiYZ8SKUzXpbSPUPmqcWfuc/LcHfQmOCKiY/EnTDOKI=\r\n', 'Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2014 14:21:23 GMT\r\n', 'Connection: keep-alive\r\n', 'Content-Length: 123\r\n'], 'dict': {'content-length': '123', 'expires': 'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT', 'x-fb-debug': 'fiYZ8SKUzXpbSPUPmqcWfuc/LcHfQmOCKiY/EnTDOKI=', 'x-fb-rev': '1086465', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-store', 'date': 'Mon, 20 Jan 2014 14:21:23 GMT', 'access-control-allow-origin': '*', 'content-type': 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8', 'www-authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "unknown_error" "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."'}, 'typeheader': 'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8', 'encodingheader': None, 'seekable': 0, 'unixfrom': '', 'plisttext': '; charset=UTF-8', 'plist': ['charset=UTF-8']}{
   'fp':None,
   'status':'',
   'startofbody':None,
   'startofheaders':None,
   'subtype':'javascript',
   'type':'text/javascript',
   'maintype':'text',
   'headers':[
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n',
      'Cache-Control: no-store\r\n',
      'Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8\r\n',
      'Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT\r\n',
      'Pragma: no-cache\r\n',
      'WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "unknown_error" "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."\r\n',
      'X-FB-Rev: 1086465\r\n',
      'X-FB-Debug: fiYZ8SKUzXpbSPUPmqcWfuc/LcHfQmOCKiY/EnTDOKI=\r\n',
      'Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2014 14:21:23 GMT\r\n',
      'Connection: keep-alive\r\n',
      'Content-Length: 123\r\n'
   ],
   'dict':{
      'content-length':'123',
      'expires':'Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT',
      'x-fb-debug':'fiYZ8SKUzXpbSPUPmqcWfuc/LcHfQmOCKiY/EnTDOKI=',
      'x-fb-rev':'1086465',
      'connection':'keep-alive',
      'pragma':'no-cache',
      'cache-control':'no-store',
      'date':'Mon, 20 Jan 2014 14:21:23 GMT',
      'access-control-allow-origin':'*',
      'content-type':'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8',
      'www-authenticate':'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "unknown_error" "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."'
   },
   'typeheader':'text/javascript; charset=UTF-8',
   'encodingheader':None,
   'seekable':0,
   'unixfrom':'',
   'plisttext':'; charset=UTF-8',
   'plist':[
      'charset=UTF-8'
   ]
}
```

The weirdest part is that posting to social groups does work(using Facebook), and that by sending the same post object through the Graph debugger everything goes through smoothly!

Have anyone encountered this behavior before?, is there a way to fix it?.